# GoldenDict doesn't launch. What do I do?

Tags: goldendict

[GoldenDict](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/goldendict.1.html) worked fine but one day simply stopped launching. The process is there, takes 29.4 MBs of storage, but the app doesn't launch. I uninstalled it and reinstalled again. No luck so far. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

After removing and before installing goldendict, do: `mv ~/.goldendict ~/.goldendict.bk` in case if your user's goldendict configuration files were corrupted.

Maybe you've tried to reinstall it using `sudo apt remove goldendict && sudo apt install goldendict`, which doesn't purge all package files, which could be broken. To reinstall `goldendict` use the next command:

```
sudo apt purge goldendict libeb16 libopencc2 libopencc2-data
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade \
    && sudo apt install goldendict
```

Also, you could install it using snap:

```
sudo snap install goldendictionary --classic
```

to check if it works, however it has the same version, so if purging/installing helps, it is not needed to install it using snap.

Also, as @SadaharuWakisaka mentioned, you could have issues with Wayland trying to launch goldendict. Try to launch it using:

```
Exec=env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb goldendict
```

Comment: You could also mention removing/renaming relevant files in the user's home folder in case they're the cause of the problem. `purge` would only take care of system files.

Comment: 20.04 snap classic version only works, wayland problem, `Exec=env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb goldendict` probably a workaround but I am not sure. I hope Goldendict/universe would run 20.04 LTS forever, one of my favourite software.